# Any guides for dummies to setting up a VPN?

Tags: networking, centos, vpn, openvpn

I am looking for a guide to setting up a VPN on a VPS, most of the guides don't explain certain elements and I've been left feeling clueless halfway through them. For example when I was installing openVPN the guide was talking about easy-rsa being in a folder in /usr/share/easyVPN but it simply was not present, so I had to manually get it and after everything I just didn't understand where I was supposed to get the IP's for the bridges etc, it was overall, very confusing.

The guide needs to make no use of a GUI, as the VPN is manipulated solely over secure shell, the OS is CentOS 6 as well, as I can't seem to find one for CentOS 6 either.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have yu tried using one of the CentOS 5 ones from HowtoForge? http://www.howtoforge.com/openvpn-server-on-centos-5.2

Answer (score 1):

I found several:

*CentOS 6*

- [How to Setup and Configure an OpenVPN Server on CentOS 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6)
- [How to Build OpenVPN Server on CentOS 6.x](http://www.servermom.com/how-to-build-openvpn-server-on-centos-6-x/732/)
- [OpenVPN Community Wiki and Tracker -  RHEL6](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos)
- [How to create a OpenVPN VPN Server on CentOS 6 64bit.](http://vpsdatabase.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=2)
- [Secure Communications with OpenVPN on CentOS 6](https://library.linode.com/networking/openvpn/centos-6)

*CentOS 5*

- [OpenVPN Server On CentOS 5.2](http://www.howtoforge.com/openvpn-server-on-centos-5.2)